# Flutter - Open Specific Page from FCM Background Notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to my Flutter app. As of right now, when I click on a background notification it proceeds to open the app.

That's nice but I would like it to be that after clicking the background push notification, it opens a specific page in my app. **How does one do this?** I have researched this thoroughly and can't seem to find anything that makes sense. Code examples or detailed links preferred please.

Comment: Have you tried using Navigator.pushNamed from within the onResume block in your fcm.configure function?

Comment: Hmm, no. I just use Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageClass()); Whats the difference between this and Navigator.pushNamed? @GrahamD

Comment: That should also work, I guess. I have named routes in my main.dart so I use pushNamed. Works for me. I suggest you post the code you have tried (the fcm.configure method particularly) so we have a chance of helping.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved this by adding `"click_action": 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'` to my data payload!